# Generating random dice rolls and measuring frequency of outcomes

Tags: c++, boost, random

Here I am rolling dice and storing the results in a map (int for occurrences of a number, long for frequency i.e. occurrences / trials). Here is a typical output:

```
Please select the number of trials:
100
Dice roll of 1 has 327% outcomes
Dice roll of 2 has 16722170% outcomes
Dice roll of 3 has 327% outcomes
Dice roll of 4 has 14872209% outcomes
Dice roll of 5 has 327% outcomes
Dice roll of 6 has 16724069% outcomes
```

As you can see the frequencies are all discombobulated. They should total to 1. I have tried messing with the precision but that doesn't appear to be the source of my problem. The code is rather simple. Can anyone pinpoint my problem? Kind regards.

```
#include <boost/random.hpp> 
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>            
#include <boost/Random/detail/const_mod.hpp> // LCG class
#include <map>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    //throwind dice
    //Mersenne Twister
    boost::random::mt19937 myRng;

    //set the seed
    myRng.seed(static_cast<boost::uint32_t> (time(0)));

    //uniform in range [1,6]
    boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<int> six(1,6);

    map<int, long> statistics;    //structure to hold outcome + frequencies
    int outcome;    //current outcome

    cout << "Please select the number of trials:" << endl;
    int trials;    //# of trials
    cin >> trials;
    int oc1; int oc2; int oc3; int oc4; int oc5; int oc6;    //outcomes
    for (int i = 0; i < trials; ++i)
    {
        outcome = six(myRng);

        if (outcome == 1)
        {
            oc1++;
            statistics[1] = oc1 / trials;
        }

        if (outcome == 2)
        {
            oc2++;
            statistics[2] = oc2 / trials;
        }

        if (outcome == 3)
        {
            oc3++;
            statistics[3] = oc3 / trials;
        }

        if (outcome == 4)
        {
            oc4++;
            statistics[4] = oc4 / trials;
        }

        if (outcome == 5)
        {
            oc5++;
            statistics[5] = oc5 / trials;
        }

        if (outcome == 6)
        {
            oc6++;
            statistics[6] = oc6 / trials;
        }
    }

    for (int j = 1; j <= 6; ++j)
        cout << "Dice roll of " << j << " has " << statistics[j] << "% outcomes" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you initializing outcomes variables? (`oc1` to `oc6`)

Comment: I tried "int outcome = six(myRng);" but with no success. I also initialized oc1, oc2, oc3 etc. to 0, but that gives me straight "0% outcomes".

Comment: J-Kubik has found your problem. The default initialization of ints is a random number (usually whatever happens to be there in memory already). Just set all you `oc` variables to 0 and you should be fine

Comment: There still is additional problem - your percentages cannot be calculated with int's - your division os dropping the result. use for example `(oc1 * 100)/trials`

Comment: Your ocN variables aren't initialized to anything.  They are unlikely to start at 0 unless you initialize them to it.  `oc1 / trials` is integer division as well which will give you 0 for fractional results.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I appreciate the guidance. I think I can fix it now.

Comment: You could greatly simplify your code by using an array to count the number of times each number is chosen.  You could also just calculate the statistics at the end.

Comment: Also, why not use `boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<int> six(0,5);` and avoid the silly index offsets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, you did not initialize `oc1, oc2,` etc.

But your code could use some simplification:

```
int oc[6] = {};
for (int i = 0; i < trials; ++i)
{
    outcome = six(myRng);
    oc[outcome-1]++;
    statistics[outcome] = oc[outcome-1] / trials;
}
```

This not only initializes the values, but shortens the loop.

However, as the comment suggested, if you want floating point, you need to change your types to allow floating point values, not integer.